# Can you destroy your own starbases?

Tags: eclipse

The title says it all.

> Can I destroy my own starbase?

Why would you want this? You might want to 'move' the starbase to another system. By destroying your own starbase you can build a new one at the desired new location. Only of course when you have built all starbases and have none left.

If so, should I have to shoot it? or pick it off the board (is it then a build/move action)?

Comment: Be me. See Eclipse tag. Almost flag to move to Stack Overflow. Realize I'm dumb. Post comment saying so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. The rules don't specifically clarify this; but there is nothing that would ever allow you to destroy a starbase or ship of your own. A combat only occurs when multiple ships/starbases belonging to different players are in the same sector; and combat is the only way that the rules allow for something to be removed from the board.